# Why isnt my JavaFX Progress Indicator not updating?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have the following layout in my JavaFX application,

```
StackPane
   - BorderPane 
    - Text (on Top) 
    - Vbox (on Center)
        - ProgressIndicator
        - Label
   - BorderPane
        - Scroll Pane (with Tile Pane inside) (Center of Border Pane)
        - Button (Bottom of Border)

   - BorderPane
     - Vbox (on Center)
       - Progress Indicator
       - Label
     - Button ( Bottom)
```

When showing the first Border Pane, the Progress Indicator works perfectly. I set it up using the following code,

```
progress.progressProperty().bind(iconLoadTask.progressProperty());
progresspane.visibleProperty().bind(iconLoadTask.runningProperty());
```

When the iconLoadTask completes, the progress pane becomes invisible and the next pane is shown correctly.

From the next BorderPane (which has the Scroll pane), I show the last border pane (with a progress indicator - indeterminate). This progress indicator doesnt animate at all.

Edit:

As suggested, I have tried reproducing this issue,

I have the following controller file. Here you can see two progress indicators (progress and stopProfInd). progress is updated from the task appLoadTask. This is a finite task and I can update progress from the task. This works fine.

I have another indicator called stopProfInd. This is set indeterminate from Scene Builder. Here you can see that I make that pane visible. I expect the indicator to animate, but it doesn't.

```
public class AppController
    implements Initializable {

@FXML
private StackPane stackpaneapps;

@FXML
private BorderPane progresspane;

@FXML
private ProgressIndicator progress;

@FXML
private ProgressIndicator stopProfInd;

@FXML
private BorderPane profilingpane;

@FXML
private Label devicename;

private ObservableValue<Number> profProperty;

// Reference to the main application.
private Main mainApp;

private AppIconsTask appLoadTask;

private ProfilingTask prTask;

private Queue<MyVbox> clickedAppQueue;

@Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
    clickedAppQueue = new LinkedList<MyVbox>();
}
/**
 * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
 *
 * @param mainApp
 */
public void setMainApp(Main mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
}

/**
 * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
 *
 * @param task
 *
 */
public void setAppLoadTask(AppIconsTask task) {
    this.appLoadTask = task;
    progress.progressProperty().bind(appLoadTask.progressProperty());
    progresspane.visibleProperty().bind(appLoadTask.runningProperty());
    appLoadTask.setOnSucceeded(t -> drawAppIcons(appLoadTask.getApps()));
    profilingpane.setVisible(false);
}


void drawAppIcons(ObservableList<App> apps){
    progress.setVisible(false);
    profilingpane.setVisible(true);

    prTask = new ProfilingTask();
    stopProfInd.progressProperty().bind(prTask.progressProperty());
    new Thread(prTask).start();
}
}
```

Any clues?

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="263.0" prefWidth="304.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.gamebench.ios.controller.AppController">
   <children>
      <StackPane fx:id="stackpaneapps" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
         <children>
            <BorderPane fx:id="profilingpane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <center>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                     <children>
                        <ProgressIndicator fx:id="stopProfInd" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </center>
            </BorderPane>
            <BorderPane fx:id="progresspane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <center>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                     <children>
                        <ProgressIndicator fx:id="progress" maxHeight="100.0" maxWidth="100.0" prefHeight="68.0" prefWidth="77.0" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </center>
            </BorderPane>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Adding Task implementation as requested. The following is for appIconsTask which works well.

```
    protected ObservableList<App> call() throws Exception {
    String deviceId = "blah";
    /* We will start before we get the list of installed apps */
    updateProgress(0.0f , 100);
    // Get list of installed apps
    App[] installedApps = getAppsList(deviceId , false);
    appList = FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<App>());
    int numApps = installedApps.length;

    double progress = 1.0f;
    for(App app: installedApps){

        byte[] pngData;
        pngData = comm.getAppIcon(deviceId, app.getBundleId());
        app.setAppIcon(pngData);
        appList.add(app);
        updateProgress((progress/numApps)*100, 100);
        progress += 1.0f;
    }
    return appList;
}
```

Task implementation for the next progress indicator,

```
protected Void call() throws Exception {
    double f = 1.0;
    while(!getStopProf()){
        Thread.sleep(30);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Reproduction of the issue here,
https://github.com/h-karthik/BugReproStackOverflow

Comment: Without the code it is really difficult to get a clue.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha added some code where the ProgressIndicators progressProperty is set.

Comment: There is [not enough code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to allow your question to be answered.  Create something absolutely minimal which executes and reproduces the issue and edit your question to include it.

Comment: @jewelsea added the Controller code. I will add in the FXML too

Comment: You still haven't posted anything anyone can actually run. Please read the link @jewelsea provided, and follow those directions. The point is to create the smallest possible example that shows the problem and can be executed by other people. You haven't even posted your task implementation... or where you create the task, or how the task is supplied to the controller... I would recommend trying to write a new example, completely from scratch, that shows the problem.

Comment: @James_D There is nothing special in the task. It will take some effort to whittle down my code into a reproducible example. As I mentioned in the answer below, it looks like an issues with StackPane (with BorderPanes) and ProgressIndicators. Using opacity as a workaround is ok for me. setVisible for the pane is causing issues.

Comment: So you can't be bothered to take the time to create an example demonstrating the issue, but you expect people to volunteer their time to wade through your code and make guesses about the parts you didn't post in order to help you with your problem? Good luck with that.

Comment: @James_D Apologies. Didnt mean it like that. I have created a full working sample showing the problem. Please do have a look.

Comment: Gents. I have added reproducible code. Instead of downvoting, please suggest a solution.

Comment: Again, please provide a minimal example. Perhaps "minimal" means something different to you than it does to me: I am using [this definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minimal). As far as I can tell, you have one task, which when it completes starts a second task, and makes a pane visible. That does not need seven classes (including some with native implementations, seriously?) and two FXML files.

Comment: @James_D Uploaded a version with further classes removed. But before that, can you please keep your cynical attitude at home. I accepted my mistake and put up the source. You don't have to reciprocate and apologise but be normal and keep your attitude at bay. Now if you are man enough, find the solution and post it here.

Comment: Thanks for the update: that is much easier to read and to run. What I see is the first progress indicator go from 0% to 100% over 6 seconds; then the second progress indicator becomes visible in an indeterminate state. Is that not what you are seeing? If so, what did you expect that's different? If not, what JDK version are you using? Maybe you are running into [this bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-33261), which was fixed in JDK 8u20.

Comment: And, yeah, perhaps the previous comment was a little "snide", but I was already frustrated with looking at questions with an inappropriate amount of code (either too little or too much). Probably should just have left the question alone. FWIW narrowing things down to a minimal example might actually get you to the answer yourself more quickly than even posting here. At a minimum it will make it easier (& therefore quicker) for others to answer (or give you the correct search at the [bug database](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa)).

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the answer. I accepted the answer :) I was trying to use fx:define in SceneBuilder. It looks like I have to manually edit the xml. Is that correct? If I manually edit the code, then FXML doesnt load that file anymore. Any clues.I am using SceneBuilder 2.0

Comment: Ah, not sure. I don't use SceneBuilder a whole lot, but I suspect you probably can't create an `<fx:define>` element from within it and you have to manually edit it. It should read such a file, but there is a [bug filed for this](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/DTL-6812) which is fixed in version 2.0.1 (not sure where to get that version...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running into [this bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-33261) which, at the time of writing, is fixed in the latest GA release (JDK 8u20). The easiest fix, if it's possible for you to do, is to upgrade to and require that version.

If you can't do that, the next most intuitive option is to avoid use of `setVisible(...)` and just add the progress indicator to the scene graph when you need it. You can define elements in FXML which are not contained in the scene graph by using [`<fx:define>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#define_elements). Inject this as usual, and then just add the element to the scene graph as you need it. (You can remove it in similar fashion, if you need.)

Your FXML file becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="263.0" prefWidth="304.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="com.stackoverflow.repro.controller.AppController">
    <children>
        <StackPane fx:id="stackpaneapps" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0"
            AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
            <children>
                <BorderPane fx:id="progresspane" prefHeight="200.0"
                    prefWidth="200.0">
                    <center>
                        <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0"
                            BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                            <children>
                                <ProgressIndicator fx:id="progress" maxHeight="100.0"
                                    maxWidth="100.0" prefHeight="68.0" prefWidth="77.0" />
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                    </center>
                </BorderPane>
            </children>

        </StackPane>
    </children>
    <fx:define>
        <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" fx:id="profilingpane">
            <center>
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0"
                    BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <children>
                        <ProgressIndicator fx:id="stopProfInd" />
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </center>
        </BorderPane>
    </fx:define>
</AnchorPane>
```

and the controller becomes

```
package com.stackoverflow.repro.controller;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.stackoverflow.repro.Main;
import com.stackoverflow.repro.tasks.AppIconsTask;
import com.stackoverflow.repro.tasks.ProfilingTask;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;


public class AppController
        implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private StackPane stackpaneapps;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane progresspane;

    @FXML
    private ProgressIndicator progress;

    @FXML
    private ProgressIndicator stopProfInd;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane profilingpane;

    // Reference to the main application.
    private Main mainApp;

    private AppIconsTask appLoadTask;

    private ProfilingTask prTask;


    @Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
    public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
    }
    /**
     * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
     *
     * @param mainApp
     */
    public void setMainApp(Main mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;
    }

    /**
     * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
     *
     * @param task
     *
     */
    public void setAppLoadTask(AppIconsTask task) {
        this.appLoadTask = task;
        progress.progressProperty().bind(appLoadTask.progressProperty());
        progresspane.visibleProperty().bind(appLoadTask.runningProperty());
//        profilingpane.setVisible(false);
        appLoadTask.setOnSucceeded(t -> drawAppIcons());

    }


    void drawAppIcons(){
//        profilingpane.setVisible(true);
        stackpaneapps.getChildren().add(profilingpane);
        prTask = new ProfilingTask();
        new Thread(prTask).start();
    }
}
```

Your workaround with the opacity works as well, but this just feels like a more natural approach. There is a slight difference in functionality, which is not evident from everything being in a `StackPane`. With both `setVisible` (when it works correctly) and the `setOpacity(...)` workaround, the progress indicator will take up space in the layout. With adding and removing it when it is required, it will not take up space in the layout when it is not present. So  the choice of approach probably depends on how you want it to behave in terms of layout.

Just a couple of other comments about your code:

If you make the thread running the `prTask` a daemon thread, it will not prevent the JVM from exiting when you close the last window. Obviously you may have other mechanisms for shutting this down in your real app, but it can be a useful trick (and is less annoying if you're testing this from Eclipse...):

```
    Thread prThread = new Thread(prTask);
    prThread.setDaemon(true);
    prThread.start();
```

Also, your threading code in the profiling task looks like it is not quite correct. The `stopProf` field is almost certainly changed on a different thread to the one on which it is read. This means there is no guarantee of liveness of the field (there can be an arbitrary delay, possible indefinite, between it being changed in one thread and that change being visible in another). You should do one of the following:

1. Mark the field as `volatile`, or
2. Mark the `getStopProf()` and `setStopProf(...)` methods as `synchronized`, or
3. Replace the `boolean` field with an `AtomicBoolean`.

This third option is the one I prefer (favor high-level APIs over low-level primitives):

```
package com.stackoverflow.repro.tasks;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;

/**
 * Created by karthik on 17/02/15.
 */
public class ProfilingTask extends Task<Void> {

    AtomicBoolean stopProf;
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        double f = 1.0;
        while(!getStopProf()){
            Thread.sleep(30);

        }
        return null;
    }
    public boolean getStopProf(){
        return stopProf.get();
    }

    public void setStopProf(boolean stop){
        stopProf.set(stop);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hi James_D, Thanks for the very elaborate answer. Yes, you are right, I did hid the bug as I was using 1.8_u05. I upgraded to 1.8_u31 and the bug disappeared. Although, I do like your suggestion to use fx:define. I will go ahead and change my implementation. Thanks for pointing out the use of AtomicBoolean. One more thing to change :)

Answer (score -2):

So, it turns out that it might be my ignorance or possibly a bug.

In my code instead of the following line

```
profilingpane.setVisible(true);
```

I use the following and the problem goes away. This is more of a hack to solve the problem.

```
profilingpane.setOpacity(0.0);
```

And then when I want the pane to show up,

```
profilingpane.setOpacity(1.0);
```

Comment: This is just awful. You are wasting everyone's time who cares to help you. And this hack doesn't help anyone who runs into a similar problem.

Comment: @Roland..Apologies. I was really frustrated yesterday as I had been having a go at the problem for 4-5 hours and was behind on some tasks. I have added the link that contains the full source. Please do have a look.